# From where to download SoapUI-Pro-5.1.1 installer?

Tags: testing, download, automation, automated-tests, soapui

> I am searching for particular download  SoapUI-Pro-5.1.1 installer.
>   Try to search but it updated to 5.2 and NG Version.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Old SoapUI Pro versions can be found at http://dl.eviware.com/list_soapui2.html

Comment: Thanks, but which one to use how i can know? I am using Windows.5.1.1/SoapUI-Pro-5.1.1-win32-standalone-bin.zip.md5 
 5.1.1/SoapUI-Pro-5.1.1-win32-standalone-bin.zip.sha1 
 5.1.1/SoapUI-Pro-5.1.1-windows-bin.zip             
 5.1.1/SoapUI-Pro-5.1.1-windows-bin.zip.md5         
 5.1.1/SoapUI-Pro-5.1.1-windows-bin.zip.sha1        
 .

Comment: actually i have 2 Windows Server and i am new in Office their is one Server already running 5.1.1 Version adn now, she told me to download 5.1.1 on another Server. I never work with Server so bit nervous.thanks for the help